# How do I organise a PHP foreach loop by the filename it spits out?

Tags: php, foreach

Alreet All

I'm trying to organise a list of files that are returned by a foreach loop - the files are labelled with a month: for eg report - january 2011, report - february 2011 etc

They currently spit them out in random order, eg july, february, december, march and I want them to appear in order like, january, february, march, april etc.

Can you guys shed any light on how I would do this.

This is my function:

```
function getDirectoryList($directory) {
$results = array();
$handler = opendir($directory);
while ($file = readdir($handler)) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != "img") {
        $results[] = $file;
    }
}
closedir($handler);
return $results;
}
```

This is the call to the function: (note "filepath" is set using define())

```
$files = getDirectoryList(filepath.$username."/".date("Y"));
```

This is the foreach loop:

```
foreach ($files as $f) {    
$path_parts = pathinfo(filepath.$f);
$dir = $path_parts['dirname'];
$base = $path_parts['basename'];
$ext = $path_parts['extension'];
$fname = $path_parts['filename'];

echo "<div class='file ".$ext."'>".
    "<a href='".downloadpath.$username."/".$f."' target='_blank' title='Download $f'>". $fname ."</a>
    <span class='del'><a href='../inc/delete.php?id=".$_GET["id"]."&amp;f=$f' title='Delete $f'>Delete</a></span>
    </div>";
}
```

Comment: whay just not to use sort for your array?

Comment: The question is essentially "how to sort this array by date"... `sort()` won't do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sort the array before you loop through it

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
  $a = pathinfo(filepath.$a);
  $b = pathinfo(filepath.$b);
  $months = array(1 => 'January', 2 => 'February', 3 => 'March', 4 => 'April', 5 => 'May', 6 => 'June', 7 => 'July', 8 => 'August', 9 => 'September', 10 => 'October', 11 => 'November', 12 => 'December');

  $a_val = $b_val = 0;
  foreach ($months as $value => $month) {
    if (stripos($a['filename'], $month) !== false) $a_val = $value;
    if (stripos($b['filename'], $month) !== false) $b_val = $value;
  }
  return ($a_val < $b_val) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($files, 'cmp');
```

Comment: But this will sort them alphabetically, while the goal is to sort them in chronological order.

Comment: +1 same as i tried to write =) your get the badge #fast_writer =)

Comment: You may also group them into an month-array, while looping through the foreach, having: `array('january' => array('report1.csv', 'report2.csv'), 'february' => array('report3.csv')` That array should be pre-sorted by month-order

Comment: You got the months array created and iterated for each call to cmp. There is space left for optimization.

Comment: @Jens We could write the comparison function in C and compile it as a PHP extension too. There is always space left for optimization. Your comments today are very strange.

Comment: I'm not sure how to fit this into my scripting.

Comment: Are they? I will try to be more focused.

Comment: @Peter Put it before your foreach loop.

Comment: @Dan - i did that, placed the function in a global include file where all my functions are and pout the     uasort($files, 'cmp');    above the foreach, now i get nothing.

Comment: I have made an update to the function, though I don't think it should "give you nothing" either way. It would just fail to change the order. Unless you meant you now get a completely blank response from your script, in which case you are probably getting an error and have display_errors turned off.

Comment: seriously i get a blank page where i suypposed to get a list of fiules: i have this at top of page to    ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL^E_STRICT^E_NOTICE);

Comment: Ah Dan you are a legend! big mistake on my side, had some code left in from previous attempts, some apostrophe was braking it - my bad - your code worked a treat! A HUGE Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Use `usort` to sort your array.

```
usort($files, 'cmp');
```

Use an associative array to set up the compare critieron:

```
$months = array ("january" => 0, "february" => 1, ...);
```

Setup a compare function:

```
function cmp($file1, $file2) {
    $months = array ("january" => 0, "february" => 1, ...);
    // or global $months;
    // or $this->months;
    $month1 = ... extract month from $file1;
    $month2 = ... extract month from $file2;
    return $months[$month1] < $months[$month2] ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Extract the month string from your file:

```
preg_match("/^\w+/", $file, $match);
$month = $match[0];
```

Edit:

The array $months does not need be be stored within the cmp method. This will cause the array to be created each time the method is called. Use instead an OOP approach or the global keyword `global $months`.

Comment: If you don't contain your $months array in the function you're polluting the global variable space, this would mess things up if you have a $months variable elsewhere in your code.

Comment: You may set up a static class as well hosting the month array. Or whatever you want. Scopes are not subject of this question.

Answer (score 0):

try [ksort](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) with [filemtime](http://uk.php.net/filemtime)

```
function getDirectoryList($directory) {
$results = array();
    $handler = opendir($directory);
    while ($file = readdir($handler)) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != "img") {
            $inDate = filemtime($directory.$file);
            $results[$inDate] = $file;
        }
    }
    closedir($handler);
    ksort($results);
    return $results;
}
```

Comment: that's why I added ``$results[$inDate] = $file;`` to make a right order

Comment: I meant we don't know if january has been modified before february.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getSortableDate( $s ) {
    $months = array( 'january' => '01', 'february' => '02', 'march' => '03', ... );
    preg_match( '/^(\w+) (\d+)$/', $s, $matches );
    return $matches[2].$months[ $matches[1] ];
}

function cmp($a, $b) {
    return ( getSortableDate( $a['filename'] ) < getSortableDate( $b['filename'] ) ) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort( $files, 'cmp' );
```

Alternatively you can apply getSortableDate() to all filenames before sorting and then sort using simple string comparison, this will make things faster by preventing redundant getSortableDate() calls.

But I wouldn't personally do it this way, it's an overkill, just rename your files to 2011-01 2011-02 etc.. so they can be compared as strings.

Comment: getSortableDate is invoked 2 times for each cmp call which results in having a lot of indentical $match arrays created.

Answer (score 0):

Use usort on your $files aray with a custom function.

```
function my_sort($a,$b) {
     $month = array (
        'january' => 1,
        'february' => 2,
        'march' => 3,
        'april' => 4,
        'may' => 5,
        'june' => 6,
        'july' => 7,
        'august' => 8,
        'september' => 9,
        'october' => 10,
        'november' => 11,
        'december' => 12
    );

    // Might need to extract month from filename here
    $a_idx = $month[$a['filename']];
    $b_idx = $month[$b['filename']];

    if ($a_idx == $b_idx) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return ($a_idx < $b_idx ? -1 : 1);
    }
}

usort($files,'my_sort');
```